# Lombok @EqualsAndHashCode and Jhipster TestUtil.equalsVerifier

Tags: jhipster, equals, lombok

I am using Jhipster and Lombok for my Java project.

I removed the entity object equals() and hashcode() method generated by Jhipster and replaced with lombok @EqualsAndHashCode

**Originally generated By Jhipster**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 100)
    private String name;

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Category name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Category)) {
            return false;
        }
        return id != null && id.equals(((Category) o).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    // prettier-ignore
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", name='" + getName() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

**Modified to use Lombok**

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 100)
    private String name;

}
```

The problem is the test generated by Jhipster below fails. At the last 2 lines of the test

```
    /**
     * Verifies the equals/hashcode contract on the domain object.
     */
    public static <T> void equalsVerifier(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
        T domainObject1 = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
        assertThat(domainObject1.toString()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(domainObject1).isEqualTo(domainObject1);
        assertThat(domainObject1.hashCode()).isEqualTo(domainObject1.hashCode());
        // Test with an instance of another class
        Object testOtherObject = new Object();
        assertThat(domainObject1).isNotEqualTo(testOtherObject);
        assertThat(domainObject1).isNotEqualTo(null);
        // Test with an instance of the same class
        T domainObject2 = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
        assertThat(domainObject1).isNotEqualTo(domainObject2);  //this fails
        // HashCodes are equals because the objects are not persisted yet
        assertThat(domainObject1.hashCode()).isEqualTo(domainObject2.hashCode()); //this also fails
    }
```

May I know what is the purpose of the test?

every `clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();` object should not be equal with each other? The content of the object is the same. Why not?

every `clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();` object should have same hashCode? If so, why lombok @EqualsAndHashCode gives different hashcode?

How can I fix the problem?

*Note that the class extends AbstractAuditingEntity

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false, length = 50, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "last_modified_by", length = 50)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant lastModifiedDate = Instant.now();

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Instant getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Instant createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public Instant getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(Instant lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Lombok `@Data` on `@Entity` annotated classes is a bad idea: https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/ and personally I would not recommend using Lombok at all especially for beginners, there are too many hidden traps. That's the reason why JHipster team does not use it.